# Is it possible to create an error and assign it to an error subtype variable in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, error-handling, variant, subtype

Theoretically, if `VarType(foo)` returns `10` or `vbError`, it means that `foo` is an error. Am I wrong?

So how do I force this to happen? Is it even possible to force `foo` to hold an error? If it's not, then I don't understand why Error is a variable subtype.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript doesn't support all of the Variant subtypes. For example, try to create a variable of subtype `vbDecimal` (VBScript doesn't even have the `CDec()` function to allow you to type-convert to Decimal) or try to create an array of anything other than the `vbVariant` subtype.

These [constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237865.aspx) are part of the Variant specification defined by the OLE Automation libraries. VB/VBA supports all of these subtypes and it seems VBScript adopted the same constants, even though it has no native support for many of them.

Answer (score 0):

In VBScript hold:

1. If an object has a default property, `VarType (object)` returns the type of its default property.
2. The default property of the `Err` object is Number. `Err.Number` contains an integer.

Thus, `VarType(Err)` returns `3` as well as `VarType(foo)` in next example:

```
 On Error Resume Next
 Dim foo
 Set foo = Err
 se tr 'this line raises an error
 Wscript.Echo CBool( IsObject( foo)) _
  & vbNewLine & VarType( foo) _
  & vbNewLine & foo.Number _
  & vbNewLine & foo.HelpFile _
  & vbNewLine & foo.HelpContext _
  & vbNewLine & foo.Source _
  & vbNewLine & foo.Description
```